# How can I call authentication with passportjs, nodejs and azure-ad-oauth2 from my react app?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I implemented a backend using passporjs, nodejs and azure-ad-oauth2 for my react application. I want to use the endpoint in my react application, the problem is that I don't know how to do it can anyone help me how I can do that logic? Below is what I tried to do:

**app.js:**

```
import express from 'express';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import cors from 'cors';
import passport from 'passport';
import AzureAdOAuth2Strategy from 'passport-azure-ad-oauth2';

const app = express();

dotenv.config();

const Port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

passport.use(
  new AzureAdOAuth2Strategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: 'https://www.example.net/auth/azureadoauth2/callback',
      resource: process.env.RESOURCE,
      tenant: 'contoso.onmicrosoft.com',
    },
    function (accessToken, refresh_token, params, profile, done) {
      var waadProfile = profile || jwt.decode(params.id_token, '', true);

      User.findOrCreate({ id: waadProfile.upn }, function (err, user) {
        done(err, user);
      });
    }
  )
);

//middleware
app.use(express(cors));

//routes
app.get('/auth/azureadoauth2', passport.authenticate('azure_ad_oauth2'));

app.get(
  '/auth/azureadoauth2/callback',
  passport.authenticate('azure_ad_oauth2', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function (req, res) {
    // Successful authentication, redirect home.
    res.redirect('/');
  }
);
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('App is running successfully');
});

app.listen(Port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on ${Port}`);
});
```

**Login.js:**

```
function Login() {

 const handleLogin = (loginType: any) => {
    fetch('http://localhost:4000/auth/azureadoauth2').then((response) => {
      if (loginType === 'redirect') {
        instance.loginRedirect(loginRequest).catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
      }
    });
  };

  return <button onClick={handleLogin}>Login</button>;
    
  };
```

Comment: did you ever figure this one out? I am trying to do something similar.

Comment: Unfortunatly no.

Comment: Do you need AzureAdOAuth2Strategy? I was able to solve my issue w/ passport-azure-ad BearerStrategy